# Unexpected chars in the html side

Tags: django

My html is like this.

```
<div style="display:none" maxpostid="{{maxpostid}}" maxcommentid="{{maxcommentid}}"></div>
```

and passing the context like below.

```
context = {'maxpostid':postid, 'maxcommentid': commentid}

return render(request, 'sample.html', context)
```

It shows output like below.

```
<div style="display:none" maxpostid="{u&#39;id__max&#39;: 14}" maxcommentid="{u&#39;id__max&#39;: 42}"></div>
```

There are some unwanted chars coming, Am I doing anything wrong?

```
def samplehtml(request):
    postid = PostEntry.objects.all().aggregate(Max('id'))
    commentid = CommentEntry.objects.all().aggregate(Max('id'))

    context = {'maxpostid':postid, 'maxcommentid': commentid}

    return render(request, 'sample.html', context)
```

Comment: Maybe you should show what `postid` and `commentid` are and where they are coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregations return data in the form of a dictionary: ie, `{ "id__max": 42 }`. You should pass the value, rather than the entire result, to the template:

```
context = {'maxpostid': postid['id__max'], 'maxcommentid': commentid['id__max']}
```

Comment: Sir, any idea about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988324/typeerror-at-poststreambool-object-is-not-iterablerequest-method-postrequ