# TypeError at postStream↵'bool' object is not iterable↵↵Request Method: POST↵Request

Tags: django

I have below code that is expected to return top 1 record where id > jquery posted value.

```
def postStream(request):
    post = PostEntry.objects.filter(id > request.POST['maxpostid'])[:1]

    response_text = serializers.serialize('json', [post,])
    return HttpResponse(request.POST['maxpostid'], content_type='application/json')
```

Due to some reason, it gives below error.

> TypeError at postStream↵'bool' object is not iterable↵↵Request
>   Method: POST↵Request

I can confirm that `request.POST['maxpostid']` is giving expected value.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `>` sign you should use [`__gt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#gt) appendix in queryset. Try this:

```
post = PostEntry.objects.filter(id__gt=request.POST['maxpostid']).first()
```

Comment: id is the column name when i replaced it with id__gt, i got an error AttributeError at postStream↵'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta

Comment: if there is no record found, do i need to replace it with something like first or default? Is there any such option?

Comment: Do i need to remove first(), as this is crashing if no record is found

Comment: @Pankaj no you don't. In case queryset is emprty `first` will return None. See this part of doc:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first

Comment: I am trying to do it like this `postRecords = PostEntry.objects.filter(id__gt = id)
    if(postRecords.exists()):
       post = postRecords.first()
    else:
       post = None` Am I missing anything

Comment: The code line you suggested works if record is found otherwise it crashes. Error Message `AttributeError at postStream↵'NoneType' object has no attribute`

Comment: This error occures on serializing step. You need to check if object returned before serializing: `if post: response_text = serializers.serialize('json', [post,]) else: response_text = 'no record found'

Comment: Can u please suggest something here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989388/not-able-to-retrieve-primary-field-django

Answer (score 1):

```
 post = PostEntry.objects.filter(id = request.POST['maxpostid']).first()
```

you need to use = in the filter

or

to check greater

```
 post = PostEntry.objects.filter(id__gt = request.POST['maxpostid']).first()
```

and also send your data to the html

```
response_text = serializers.serialize('json', [post,])
return HttpResponse(response_text , content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: id is the column name when i replaced it with id__gt, i got an error AttributeError at postStream↵'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta

Comment: if there is no record found, do i need to replace it with something like first or default? Is there any such option?

Answer (score 0):

Use `__gt` to check and use `get` to get `maxpostid` from POST data. 
Also, I think you wanted to return serialized data:

```
post = PostEntry.objects.filter(id__gt=request.POST.get('maxpostid')).first()

data = serializers.serialize('json', [post,], fields=('id',))

return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```